# limit registered user to 1 comment per post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to limit registered users to 1 comment per post in WordPress.

I used this code below, but in this case of this it displays the message "You have commented" on the top bar of my site and does nothing.

```
global $current_user, $post;
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    comment_form();
} else {
    $usercomment = get_comments(array('user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id'=>$post->ID) );
    if($usercomment) { 
        echo '<p>You have commented</p>';
    } else {
        comment_form(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code is messed up. First you check if the user ISN'T logged in, and display the comment for those. And your comment count is checked only when the user isn't logged in (so you'll count all comments, and always get a true there for any message existing for the post). Finally, since you are simply echoing the message the output will appear at the top of the page. without knowing WHERE are you using this code, no idea where the output will be.

Comment: @yivi, thank you. exactly the echo appears at the top of the page. I used the code in public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php, but it did not work.Please support me.

Comment: @yivi, I tried $domain =  "yivoff.com"; but to no avail,

Comment: @yivi How do I contact you? your email.

Comment: If you can't figure it out from my profile, not much else I can do about it, sorry. It's easy enough to parse.

Comment: Sent you a message.